# Has jsdelivr stopped to provide js-lib concat service?

Tags: cdn

I used jsdelivr for a long time.

It has a very strong feature:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@3.2.1,jquery.ui@1.11.4

However, recently it looks like they've stopped updating this. For instance, I want to use `3.4.1`:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@3.4.1,jquery.ui@1.11.4

It says

> Couldn't find the requested release version 3.4.1.

If they've stopped supporting this feature, what else js CDN service can do this?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format changed. This is the new one:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/jquery@3.4.1,npm/jquery-ui@1.12

It now pulls the files directly from NPM